# Why can't I use JavaScript getElementsByName() with [0].style...?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

If `getElementsByName` is supposed to return an indexable list of elements, why can't I reference the only element with that name using `[0]`?

```
mycanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
mycanvas.width = 600;
mycanvas.height = 400;
ctx = mycanvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(mycanvas);

document.getElementsByName("mycanvas")[0].style.backgroundColor="#FF0000"; //this produces an "undefined is not an object" error
//mycanvas.style.backgroundColor="#FF0000" //this works
```

Comment: It's `getElementsByTagName` (returns a `NodeList`, not an array) or `getElementById` (single return value).

Comment: Why do you think something should be returned from `document.getElementsByName("mycanvas")`?

Comment: `mycanvas` is the variable name, the tagname would be `canvas` but why would you need it if you have it already as a variable?

Comment: Well zerkms, because the function name suggests that's what it would do; the element I am trying to reference is named mycanvas and I am supplying that name.. I can see now from helpful comments below that the html name attribute is what is meant rather than the other name supplied in appendChild.

Answer (score 1):

So as others have alluded to mycanvas is the variable name not the element's name attribute.

The reason what you're doing is not working yet is because you haven't set the "name" attribute of the element itself, which is what document.getElementsByName targets (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) for details.)

Give this a shot:

```
mycanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
mycanvas.width = 600;
mycanvas.height = 400;
ctx = mycanvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(mycanvas);


mycanvas.setAttribute("name", "bongo");
document.getElementsByName("bongo")[0].style.backgroundColor="#FF0000";
```

The "name" attribute is now set on your canvas element itself, ex:

```
<canvas width="600" height="400" name="bongo" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></canvas>
```

Important: Even though this works, you probably want to use a different approach since **name** should only be used on the following elements: [<a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>, and <textarea>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name)

Comment: `name` isn't a valid attribute for [`canvas`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-canvas-element) elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].style.backgroundColor="#FF0000"
```

should work, if you only have 1 canvas.

Why do you think using "mycanvas" would refer to the canvas you generated?

`document.getElementsByName` is used to refer to form elements by their `name` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Because `getElementsByName` looks for elements **by name** (e.g., `name="foo"`). Your canvas has no `name` attribute. (Nor should it; `name` isn't a valid attribute for [`canvas` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-canvas-element).)

If you want to look by **tag** name, use `getElementsByTagName` (for a "live" NodeList that gets updated as the DOM changes) or `querySelectorAll` (which returns a snapshot list that doesn't get updated).